# Jquery-Draggable Jumping Container in First Attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI to make an popup draggable and in the code

In the First Drag the Popup Jumps to top and left corner.

```js
$( ".box" ).css({"top": 0,
                 "bottom": 0,
                 "left": 0,
                 "right": 0,
                 "margin": "auto"
                });
                
$( ".box" ).draggable();
```

```css
.box{
  
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px;
    position:fixed;
}

#containment-wrapper{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dx1cxu8/47/)

Comment: Can some help m eout on this ...
here is the issue reproducable link 
http://jsfiddle.net/9dx1cxu8/47/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9dx1cxu8/47/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting its position to `0,0` remove the CSS positions will solve your issue.

```js
/*$( ".box" ).css({"top": 0,
          "bottom": 0,
          "left": 0,
          "right": 0,
          "margin": "auto"
});*/
$(".box").draggable();
```

```css
.box {
  /*left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;*/
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

#containment-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="containment-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `jqueryUI` in your code.

```js
 $( ".box" ).css({"top": 0,
                     "bottom": 0,
                     "left": 0,
                     "right": 0,
                     "margin": "auto"
                    });
                    
    $( ".box" ).draggable();
```

```css
    .box{
      
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px;
        position:fixed;
    }

    #containment-wrapper{
       width:300px;
       height:300px;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div id="containment-wrapper">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rohan Kumar correctly points out, it is because you are setting the CSS incorrectly, but his solution would leave your .top and .left at 0px.

Why are you setting CSS at all? My guess is because you want it to be draggable from some location. Edit the .css file to accomplish that in this way:

```js
$( ".box" ).draggable();
```

```css
.box{
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px;
    position:fixed;
}

#containment-wrapper{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is going to the top left because u have set the css property top and left as '0 ',  so its moving over there jus remove that .css method then u can drag it normally
**